# How can I specify a type from a dependency with typescript and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to refactor some code to use a list of signals and attach `.once` handlers to each.

```
const terminationSignals = ["SIGINT", "SIGUSR2", "SIGTERM"];

terminationSignals.forEach((sig) => {
  process.once(sig, () => {
    l("received signal", sig, "terminating");
    Shutdown();
  });
});
```

This does not work because `once` accepts `Signal`s but not arbitrary strings.

How can I extract the Signal type out of the `process` module global? I want to specify that `terminationSignals` is of type `Signal[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stumble upon it with the tsserver completion hints. The global namespace I needed to find was named `NodeJS`. So, the type was already available as `NodeJS.Signals`, defined in `node_modules/@types/node/process.d.ts`.